# Searching for a Private Framework in "Framework Search Paths"

Tags: xcode, cocoa, frameworks, bundle

I've copied a custom framework into my applications bundle however, I don't seem to be able to include it properly since I'm getting the: dyld: Library not loaded: error.

So in short, is there a xcode build settings variable that will give me my bundle path?

Answer (score 0):

If your framework is in `/Contents/Frameworks` folder then set installation directory of framework to `@executable_path/../Frameworks` in framework target or use below command.

```
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/myFramework.framework/myFramework path/myFramework.framework/myFramework
```